# I can not upload mobile and watch apk on google play store console

Tags: android, apk, version, android-wear-2.0

My problem is:

I have two APKS

1. Mobile APK(Version name-1.0 , version code - 1 , minsdkversion - 19)
2. Wear APK(Version name-1.1 , version code - 2 , minsdkversion - 23)

So first , I publish mobile apk then I publish wear(Watch) apk but i am getting error from google play store console page.

Error:-  You can't roll out this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.

Otherwise can anyone say that how to publish mobile and wear apk on google play store console.

Comment: Check this link helps you out to publishing a multiple-apks on play store. https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

Comment: @KeTaN , I read all document and applied same on google play store console but I am getting same error now

Comment: Are you sure that your wear APK has the right <uses-feature> declaration? Also, is that your first release?

Comment: @Pierre <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" /> I used  in my wear watch. My first release is related with mobile apk and second release is related with wear apk which I am trying to publish and getting error which I described before

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to have both APKs in the same release. If you've already pushed a release with one APK, then in your new release, you need to click on the button "RETAIN" on the artifact from the previous release since you'll want both your Mobile and Wear APKs to be released at the same time.

Comment: @Pierre , Thanks Its working from your solution

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Comment: KeTaN> nowhere in that google document, which I read for the 92714937437th time, does it clearly say what Pierre advised.  @Pierre should put his comment as an answer since it solved OP's issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check your existing version code of already uplaoded APK and make a new APKs of grater version of apk

> - When uplaod new APk then always create grater version of APK

e.g

**Already uploaded APK:**

```
VersionCode 0
VrsionName "1.0"
```

New APK:
**Already uploaded APK:**

```
VersionCode 1
VrsionName "1.1"
```

Check Documentation:-

- https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging
- https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Also check may be it's come older wrong uplaoded apk from "Artifact library"

Hope this may helps you.

Comment: I already mention that -Mobile APK(Version name-1.0 , version code - 1 , minsdkversion - 19)

Wear APK(Version name-1.1 , version code - 2 , minsdkversion - 23) so I first published mobile apk and then I published wear apk so as you can see that wear apk version code is greater than mobile apk so any other way to publish both apk because i am getting same error now after making greater recent apk version code as per google policy

Comment: Is is uplaoded or not?

Comment: @pierre love u man , Thanks for your solution " you need to have both APKs in the same release. If you've already pushed a release with one APK, then in your new release, you need to click on the button "RETAIN" on the artifact from the previous release since you'll want both your Mobile and Wear APKs to be released at the same time"

Comment: Great!! @dilipkumargupta :)

Comment: Thanks @InsaneCat ..U too

Comment: Welcome bro..@dilipkumargupta